# Scheduled operations in C# with option to FullStop immediately

Tags: c#, events, timer

I need to do some operations on a certain interval (e.g. from 5 to 5 minutes in a loop) but need to be able to fully stop the thing whenever I want (on push of a button).

I was thinking into using a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) class but events might fire [even after the timer is stopped](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.stop.aspx).

How can I have some code running on a timer and still be able to **immediately** bring everything to a complete stop?

Just so I am properly understood: By complete stop I mean that events stop and I can dispose of objects like the timer itself etc. I am not asking how to avoid having side effects from unexpected events that are fired after the timer is stopped!

Comment: What do you mean by 'might fire' ? 
Did you unregister the events correctly?
`Timer1.Elapsed -= new ElapsedEventHandler(Timer1_ElapsedEventHandler);`

Comment: @CSharpie: Will that matter considering that the signal to raise the Elapsed event is always queued for execution on a ThreadPool thread?

Comment: @CSharpie I agree with JohnDoDo. The way an event is raised in a multithreaded environment gives rise to an inescapable race condition, where the timer may have already started raising the event at the time you unsubscribe.

Comment: My thought was that incase he has multiple simultaneously, that it might have some sideeffects not unregistering events properly.

I just noticed, I didnt read careful enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer to this question depends a lot on a type of your operations.

Best scenario is to run a thread with a loop and listen to abort event.

```
static AutoResetEvent abort = new AutoResetEvent();
Thread worker = new Thread(WorkerThread);

void MainThread()
{
  worker.Start();
  Thread.Sleep(30000);
  abort.Set();
}    

void WorkerThread()
{
  while(true)
  {
     if(abort.WaitOne(5000)) return;
     // DO YOUR JOB
  }
}
```

When you call `abort.Set()` from another thread, this one will exit.

But if your code is long running, you won't be able to exit until job is done.
To exit immediately you will have to abort thread, but this is not too wise because of resource consumption.

Alternatively, if your operation is long running (let's say you are going through long array), you can check "abort" event state from time to time (every iteration of loop, for example) like this `abort.WaitOne(0)`.

Answer (score 1):

The race condition with the timer is unavoidable since, as you say, the callbacks are executed from the thread pool. However, I believe you can safely dispose the timer even while it's still executing the events. An option which might help is if you consider using the `System.Threading.Timer` instead of `System.Timers.Timer`, for which you can call [Timer.Dispose(WaitHandle)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b97tkt95.aspx) if you need to have a way to know when the timer events have finished executing. This will prevent race conditions for the cases where you also need to dispose of some other resource - a resource that the event consumer function will attempt to use.

As for the "immediate" requirement, the most immediate would probably be something that uses a synchronization primitive of sorts to stop execution. For example consider this:

```
static System.Timers.Timer timer;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    timer = new System.Timers.Timer(200);

    timer.Elapsed += new SomeTimerConsumer(cancelSource.Token).timer_Elapsed;
    timer.Start();

    // Let it run for a while
    Thread.Sleep(5000);

    // Stop "immediately"
    cancelSource.Cancel(); // Tell running events to finish ASAP
    lock (timer)
        timer.Dispose();

}

class SomeTimerConsumer
{
    private CancellationToken cancelTimer;

    public SomeTimerConsumer(CancellationToken cancelTimer)
    {
        this.cancelTimer = cancelTimer;
    }

    public void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        lock (timer)
        {
            // Do some potentially long operation, that respects cancellation requests
            if (cancelTimer.IsCancellationRequested)
                return;
            // More stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

This is a toy example, but it illustrates my point. The 3 lines that do the "stop immediately" have the following features:

- By the time the `Dispose` call returns, none of the `// More stuff here` code will ever execute again.
- None of the `// More stuff here` code can execute while the timer is being disposed, because of the lock.
- The previous 2 features require the lock, but they prevent the timer from stopping "immediately" because on entering the lock it needs to wait for all timer events calls to finish if they have started. For this reason I added in the cancellation as the fastest way to abort the currently executing events while still guaranteeing that they won't be executing during timer dispose.

Note: if you need multiple timer events to execute simultaneously, consider using a `ReaderWriterLockSlim` instead of a monitor.

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider one of these two options:

1. Put a safety check in the events that you need to execute. Something like a database flag. So even if the Timer fails to stop the event will bail out when the safety check fails.
2. Use something like [Quartz.Net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) for scheduling. This is really heavy handed but it'll do what you want.